# How to submit a form using the Enter key in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I have 3 buttons in a form. One of them is the submit button. How can I make it the default button to be clicked when I press the enter key. Is there a property for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a property for the form: defaultbutton.

```
<form runat="server" defaultbutton="myButton">
...
</form>
```

It is first time implemented in ASP.NET 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

Another helpful tip is that you can set the default button on asp:panel's too.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. It's been a horrific morning of debugging and now I'd like to have your children!

Answer (score 4):

Or you can do it in code - Page_load:

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSearch.UniqueID;
```

Whenever you press enter the btnSearch control will be used as default.