# How to avoid InvalidOperationException when setting the defaultbutton in ASPX content

Tags: asp.net, defaultbutton, master-pages

I am trying to set a default button in my ASPX page.  I have a master page so the form is there.  I have a panel in the content page that holds a table that organizes a number of textboxes, dropdowns and other inputs.  The last row of the table holds some buttons, one of which I want to be the default button.  After doing some research, I have tried the following with no success.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
       pnlHolder.DefaultButton = cmdSearchJob.ClientID
```

I have also tried

```
pnlHolder.DefaultButton = cmdSearchJob.UniqueID
```

and

```
Dim cmdDef As Button = pnlHolder.FindControl("cmdSearchJob")
pnlHolder.DefaultButton = cmdDef.UniqueID
```

but both throw the **exception "The DefaultButton of 'pnlHolder' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl."**.

I have seen some Javascript solutions, but was hoping to just be able to set the defaultButton for the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what it was.  Tried adding another button with no CSS, etc. that just popped up a javacsript alert() for testing.  Was able to set that as the default button when it was outside the table.  As the submit button is one of a series of buttons (not a very pretty UI, but user requirements and all that) in the table, I used this additional button and set its style to display:none and have it call the same subroutine in the code behind.

So, short answer, it wasn't seeing it in the table.

Thanks everyone for your input.

I still have no idea why it wouldn't set the button.

Comment: I have the same problem, but my button is not in a table, just in a <p> on an <asp:Content> control. I use a master page, if this is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `DefaultButton` of the parent Form.

C#:

```
 this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = cmdSearchJob.UniqueID;
```

VB?:

```
me.Page.Form.DefaultButton = cmdSearchJob.UniqueID
```

Similar issue here: [Allow Enter key to login in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237377/allow-enter-key-to-login-in-asp-net/3237556#3237556)

Comment: Tried this and got no error but no defaultButton behavior either.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I first tried ClientID, but the mentioned "UniqueID" worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to:

```
cmdSearchJob.ID
```

The panel will call FindControl to get the Client ID itself

Comment: Doesn't work.  Don't get the error but don't get the defaultButton behavior either.

Because of the Master Page, the rendered ID is "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdSearchJob".  And hardcoding it in either the code or directly in the pnlHolder properties results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set this inside the  control on the front-end?

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlHolder" DefaultButton="cmdSearchJob">
<asp:Button id="cmdSearchJob" runat="server" Text="Search" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Also, this may worth knowing, what type of object is cmdSearchJob?  Is it a standard asp.net button control?

Comment: Doing this causes the same error (The DefaultButton of 'pnlHolder' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl).  cmdSearchJob is just a plain vanilla ASP button.  It has a CSS style applied to provide left and right margins.