# how to set a default 'enter' on a certain button

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

There is a textbox on a ContentPage. When the user presses Enter in that textbox I am trying to fire a 'Submit' button on this ContentPage. I'd like to fire off that particular button's event.

Instead, there is a search textbox & button on the top of the page from a MasterPage, and this search button's event fires off.

How do I control to fire off this ContentPage's submit button, instead of the MasterPage's search button?

I am using Ektron CMS for my content management.

Comment: Do you have a panel in the content page, maybe you could set default button as the submit in that case

Comment: Thanks V4Vendetta, yes, i resolved this through adding a panel and setting the defaultbutton to submit

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The easiest way is to put the fields and button inside of a Panel and set the default button to the button you want to be activated on enter.

```
<asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server" DefaultButton="myButton">
  <%-- Text boxes here --%>
  <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Please note that this solution relies on javascript, as something like  `onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_btnSave&#39;)">` is added to your page

Comment: Perfect Solution - Thanks Kirk

Comment: @kirk What if text-box is somewhere above the button I mean not together then how we could achieve the same?

Comment: @JyotishSingh You can do the same thing if you put the `TextBox` and `Button` within the same `Panel`. Then set the _DefaultButton_ property.

Answer (score 37):

if you need to do it from code, use

```
Me.Form.DefaultButton = Me.btn.UniqueID
```

Where `btn` is your button control.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `DefaultButton` property on either a server-side [`form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) control or [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) control.  In your case, group the controls together in a `Panel` that should fire off the same button:

```
<asp:Panel ID="SearchBox" runat="server" DefaultButton="BtnSearch">
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search!" />
</asp:Panel>
....
<asp:Panel ID="UserPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="BtnUserSubmit">
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="BtnUserSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can now use UseSubmitBehavior property to disable all the buttons you don't want to fire when hitting submit (check out the documentation for more info)

```
    <asp:Button ID="BtnNotToFIre" runat="server" Text="Search" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

Comment: Absolute star! This is what I need!

Comment: And it doesn't require additional html/asp.net elements that may not work with the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft say:

```
<form id="Form1"
    defaultbutton="SubmitButton"
    defaultfocus="TextBox1"
    runat="server">
```

[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("text_box_id")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("button_id").click();
    }
    });
});
```