# asp.net javascript validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using asp.net. I have a login form. I have written Javascript validation function for this in Page.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtUsername"/></td>
        <td>Password:></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword"/></td>
        <td>Username:></td>
        <td><asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Login" onclientclick="return Validatecp()"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I focus on textbox and press enter, the entire page is reloading. I want to show the Validation on enter button press. Is that possible?

**Edit:**

*Validation Function:*

```
function Validatecp() {

            var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtName.ClientID %>').value;
            var password= document.getElementById('<%=txtTo.ClientID %>').value;

            if (name == "") {
                document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "Name Required.";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "";
            }
            if (password== "") {
                document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML = "password Required.";
                return false;
            }               
            else {
                document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML = "";
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: You need to show your validation code

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can simply add Validation Controls to your form.

Answer (score 1):

If you have written you `java-script` code then make sure that you `return false` from the js code if it is not valid and in aspx file you need to use return as follows

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Login" 
     OnClientClick="return Validate()"/>
```

### Edit -1

There is a chance that your button is not the default one so the page get refreshed when you press the enter button. For this use code below

```
<asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server" DefaultButton="myButton">
      <%-- Text boxes here --%>
      <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

some useful links

1. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETHowToCreateADefaultEnterButtonForFormsPostBacks.aspx
2. [how to set a default 'enter' on a certain button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638119/how-to-set-a-default-enter-on-a-certain-button)

Answer (score 1):

you want to validate the value of textbox when user clicks enter and focus is in textbox then use the below code:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Username:>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="save" runat="server" ID="txtUsername" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Password:>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="save" runat="server" ID="txtPassword" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Username:>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button CssClass="save" runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="submit" />
```

and jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.save').live('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            alert('heee');
            return false;
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Or if you want to validate the controls on enter button click only then use the below code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" DefaultButton="submit">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Username:>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="save" runat="server" ID="txtUsername" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Password:>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="save" runat="server" ID="txtPassword" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Username:>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button CssClass="save" runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="submit" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

and jquery code is:

```
 $('[id$=submit]').click(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            alert('heee');
            return false;
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

that's all

Answer (score 0):

You need add a add an attribute to button(btnLogin) `OnClientClick="Validate()"`.

Like:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Login" 
     OnClientClick="Validate()"/>
```

Define javascript function `Validate()` and return false if your form value is not valid.

Comment: can you write you javascript function in your question.

Comment: Billy, add this javascript function and add also jQuery plugin.

fucntion Validate(){
 var name = $("#txtPassword").val();
 if(name == ""){
  alert("Please enter your name");
  return false;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in Jquery.

```
//set this so that Jquery selector can get your button
 <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Login" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

jquery

```
$(function) () {

$('#btnLogin').click(e) {

Your javascript code here

 //put those if you don't want your page reloading
 e.preventDefault();
 return false;

 });
   });
```