# Login control, set onauthenticate="LoginAuthenticateEvent" by keypress

Tags: javascript, c#, login-control

I have asp.net Login control, example

```
<asp:Login ID="Login" onauthenticate="LoginAuthenticateEvent" runat="server"/>
```

have *.cs function like

```
protected void LoginAuthenticateEvent(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    //..
}
```

But it launch Authenticate only if pressing login Button, not by 'Enter' in textboxes.

So I decided to set this event to javascript 'onkeypress' event, and want it to check if keycode is 13(Enter) - and launch LoginAuthenticateEvent.
But there is problem - to call C# function from JS function should be static, but in my case it is 'protected void'

In JS(jQuery) code I get necessary element like this:

```
var tboxUserName = $("input[name*='UserName']");
```

I understand that there should be somethin like

```
tboxUserName.attr("onkeypress","....");
```

But how to hang there key check and make it such as onauthenticate="LoginAuthenticateEvent"?

**upd.:** Tried find control on Server side, and add TextChanged event there

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)Login.FindControl("UserName");
tb.TextChanged += tbox_TextChanged;
```

But 'TextChanged' event fires only on focus change(when click other textbox or button) - but I need to check every keypress. So question is still opened.

Comment: Think this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638119/how-to-set-a-default-enter-on-a-certain-button

Comment: Hi! No, I tried to put Login control on panel and add DefaultButton="Login$LoginButton", but with no result. Now I'm trying to hang an event from server side..

Comment: @Dave Becker Yes! It works, but instead Login$LoginButton should be Login$LoginImageButton!! :)

Comment: Glad you got it working in the end!.

Comment: @Dave Becker, if You formulate Your comment as answer I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, solution from @Dave Becker is working. In my case my Login control is branded and there was not Button, but ImageButton. In this the code looks like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelLogin" runat="server" DefaultButton="Login$LoginImageButton"> 
<asp:Login ID="Login" onauthenticate="LoginAuthenticateEvent" runat="server">
</asp:Login>
</asp:Panel>
```