# Default button for 'Enter' key with a form which does not 'runat="server"'

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I just created an ASP.NET, C# web application and for the first time i used a master page.

I learnt that you can't have two forms that runat "server" because it causes an error, so for the form (which uses for login) at the top of the master page i used a runat="server" and for a form in the content page i removed the runat attribute.

Now i cannot use the 'defaultbutton' attribute and the "Enter" key will go to the login button at the master page even if a text field in the content page is now active.

What is the solution to this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, you can't have 2 forms on a page.  You'll probably want to rethink your use of the master page, as normally it's just for holding data that's repeated across multiple pages (for example, a navigation menu) and then has a content template for the page specific content, having actual form data there doesn't normally make sense.

Comment: @user2366842 - so if i want a login area, do i need to add another content place holder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple Panel controls for this.

```
<asp:Panel ID="SearchBox" runat="server" DefaultButton="BtnSearch">
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search!" />
</asp:Panel>
....
<asp:Panel ID="UserPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="BtnUserSubmit">
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="BtnUserSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</asp:Panel>
```

[how to set a default 'enter' on a certain button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638119/how-to-set-a-default-enter-on-a-certain-button)