# Enter key should trigger after entering password in password textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have 2 ASP textboxes for Login and Password. When I enter the password and click enter it should click the login button. Tried a lot from google like placing all of them in a panel. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

`Password.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById('" + LoginRequest.UniqueID + "').click();return false;}} else {return true}; ");`

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638119/how-to-set-a-default-enter-on-a-certain-button

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the one that worked for me,

the fisrt part is added in page Load

```
txt_buscar.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "cambiaFoco('btn_buscar')")
```

and the second part in the header area of you asp page or wherever you put your scripts

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function cambiaFoco(cajadestino) 
    {
      var key = window.event.keyCode;              
      if (key == 13)  
        document.getElementById(cajadestino).focus();
    } </script>
```

just replace btn_buscar for your button ID, and txt_buscar for your password textbox ID

Comment: What is this 'cajadestino' is this id of the password

Comment: it is a parameter, you can name it whatever you want, for more information about JavaScript functions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the browser will handle this for you if you add an element to the form such as

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

I would check the HTML before the JavaScript, I'm not intimately familiar with ASP but I remember seeing some strange form arrangements in similar web frameworks.

if you need to do it in JavaScript here is what I would recommend

```
Password.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", 
    "if(event.which && event.which == 13 || event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13){
        document.getElementById(
           '" + LoginRequest.UniqueID + "'
        ).click();
     return true;
    "
);
```

it's unlikely that your input field will place a new line in the content, so there is no need to return false