# Asp.net define enter button action

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 buttons in my webpage.When i press "Enter",it auto perform "close_topic",but i want my enter button to perform "button_click".

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnLogout" Text="Close Topic" OnClick="close_topic" runat="server" />

 <asp:Button ID="ButtonTT" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClick="button_click" />

protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void close_topic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

tried to use  `<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonTT">`,but not working.

Comment: How did you use the panel? I am assuming you put the 2 buttons inside the panel.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Panel1.DefaultButton = "ButtonTT";

Comment: I'll put my suggestion in an answer since its easier to explain.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL alright,thx man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you wrap your panel around the 2 buttons? As follows:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonTT">
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogout" Text="Close Topic" OnClick="close_topic" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonTT" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClick="button_click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

**Edit**

Based on [how to set a default 'enter' on a certain button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638119/how-to-set-a-default-enter-on-a-certain-button), you can do it using code also:

```
Me.Form.DefaultButton = Me.btn.UniqueID;
```

or

```
Me.Page.Form.DefaultButton = = Me.btn.UniqueID;
```

Replacing the `Me.Page` with whatever your page name is.

Comment: but this 2 buttons in different place.not in same <asp:panel> tag

Comment: Would it be too difficult to wrap your whole page in the panel? Or just the part containing the 2 buttons, as long as you put a panel around the 2 buttons and set DefaultButton action, it will choose the right one.