# How to save fileds from asp.net when clicked on ENTER Key from Keyboard?

Tags: asp.net, .net, keyboard-events

[image: Save Fileds When Clicked on ENTER Key from KeyBoard]

Hi, Here in my screen i have few fields where i need to save to Database when clicked on ADD BUTTON , But i want to save those fields when i click on ENTER Key From Keyboard. When i enter all fields and click on ENTER key from keyboard all those fields must get saved to Data Base, how can I achieve that?

Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"defaultButton" property.  This can be applied to a asp:Form or asp:panel and will allow to to determine which button event should be triggered when the user hits the enter key

Example

```
<asp:panel defaultbutton="button2" runat="server">
        <asp:textbox id="textbox3" runat="server"/>
        <asp:button id="button2" runat="server"/>
    </asp:panel>
```

[Hitting the Enter Key to submit a form in ASP.Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yardman/archive/2010/03/01/hitting-the-enter-key-to-submit-a-form-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: I tried these way ,but when i focus on text box only that key event is getting fired..,

Comment: When i have 2 text boxes and just click on Enter key its not getting fire, and more over when i focus on one textbox only that RFV is getting fired, so here again i need to focus on all text boxes to get validation or enter some data

Comment: @Pink - check this answer ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466980/enter-key-in-asp-net-firing-wrong-button

Comment: Here when i use Tab its working..., Bcoz as tab is getting focused on each Text box....And thanks for Answer

Answer (score 0):

For a complete page You can use FORM Property -

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1">
    <div>
       <asp:Button Id="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD"></asp:Button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But here i am using Master page

Comment: When page is loaded , and when i click on Enter key that event must get fired

Comment: @pink : Pranay code is working proper for validation and focus..@pink : Please share your code...

Comment: Yes its working, But by using Tab we need to enter to every textbox and finally event is getting fired, Not as soon as we click on enter key