# asp.net login control. when enter is clicked, submit login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net login control. It works fine but you have to press the actual button login in order to login. I would like to do it if the user presses enter as well. how can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237377/allow-enter-key-to-login-in-asp-net or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201776/submit-login-control-button-when-i-hit-enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201776/submit-login-control-button-when-i-hit-enter).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but check out the [AccessKey property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.accesskey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are some workaround on this. Have a look at code snippet. (No need to add panel control)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     TextBox Password = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");
     Button ButtonLogin = (Button)Login1.FindControl("LoginButton");
     Password.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) __doPostBack('" + ButtonLogin.UniqueID + "','')");
    }
```